# how to use awk command to extract the output data from .gz file format

Tags: linux, csv, awk, gawk, gzip

I have a file in this format File.gz with content like below.

```
'0' 0 0 0 0 0 'Allowed' 'Allowed' '0' 0 '' 'E1' 3 '1' '' '000000' '00000000' '0' '0' '150' '0' '323560' '600' '1' '0' '0' '0' 150809303 'LC9' 1 1506147442 150613878 4 0 0 0 ''
```

How to use awk command to extract the output data from .gz file format? Like I want to output the file content only for field 7,8 ,11,12,22,27 in excel csv format where field 7 = allowed and field 12 = E1.

How to execute awk and print out the output in linux ?

Comment: can you unzip the file and call `awk '{print $7 $8 $11 $12 $22 $27}' extracted_file` ?

Comment: i can't gzip the file.  i want to display field 7,8 ,11,12,22,27 base on the condition where only field 7=allowed and field =12. If field 7 not equal to allowed and filed =12 , i don't want to display it.

Answer (score 5):

`awk` can't read gz files.  But you can do

```
zcat file.gz | awk -v OFS=, '{print $7, $8 ... etc}'
```

for the quoted value test, you can

```
... | awk -v OFS=, -v v7="'Allowed'" -v v12="'E1'" '$7==v7 && $12==v12 {print $7, ... etc}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{OFS=","}{print $7,$8,$11,$12,$22,$27}' filename
```

Output:

```
'Allowed','Allowed','','E1','323560','0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are searching for a one liner code.

Try the below,

```
gzip -dc File.gz|awk '{if ($7 == "allowed" && $12 == "E1") print $7","$8","$11","$12","$22","$27}'
```

explanation for - `gzip -dc` :

> `**d**` option decompresses the file
>
> `**c**` option Write output on standard output; keep original files
>   unchanged.

Comment: hi , it's able to display the output base your command.  But i want to display base on the condition where only field 7=allowed and field =12. If field 7 not equal to allowed and filed =12 , i don't want to display it. And also how to output it into a excel format or txt format in linux?

Comment: You can use if condition within awk as below
`echo $(gzip -dc File.gz)|awk '{if ($7 == "allowed" && $12 == "E1") print $7","$8","$11","$12","$22","$27}'`

Comment: how about i have multiple records ? seem like just display the first row of the record only? enter will be another row of record.   '0' 0 0 0 0 0 'Allowed' 'Allowed' '0' 0 '' 'E2' 3 '1' '' '000000' '00000000' '0' '0' '150' '0' '323560' '600' '1' '0' '0' '0' 150809303 'LC9' 1 1506147442 150613878 4 0 0 0 ''

Comment: I guess this will solve your doubt. Try just as below without `echo` ,

`gzip -dc File.gz|awk '{if ($7 == "allowed" && $12 == "E1") print $7","$8","$11","$12","$22","$27}'`

   `echo` will linearly print all the rows in File.gz `gzip` output, hence removed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have a doubt on that file content with field  '0' 'Allowed' 'Allowed' '0' 'E1' 3 '1' can't display out when using '{if ($7 =="allowed" && $12 == "E1")  for those field with double quotation marks.  if those field without double quotation marks,  0 0 0 0 0 '{if ($1 =="0" && $2 == "0"), it can display out.  How to display those content with " ' double quotation.

Comment: Try this, though its not an optimal solution.

`gzip -dc File.gz|awk -F\'\ \' '{if ($7 == "allowed" && $12 == "E1") print $7","$8","$11","$12","$22","$27}'`       Here we are giving the `' '` as feild seperator .

Comment: by the way there is some field with quotation and some field are without quotation field.   '0' '0' 0 'Allowed' 0 0 'E1'. awk like can not differentiate on it.

Comment: `awk` field separator can be a regular expression, where we can use like `-F"<FS1>|<FS2>|..."` , but here as the `space` and `' '` comes, i suppose to eliminate the `'` will be much better option. Use sed to remove `'` and use the expression as below,
`gzip -dc File.gz|sed s@\'@@g | awk  '{if ($7 == "allowed" && $12 == "E1") print $7","$8","$11","$12","$22","$27}'`